# TraceListener in OWIN Self Hosting

Tags: c#, owin

I am using `Microsoft.Owin.Hosting` to host the following, very simple web app.

Here is the call to start it:

```cs
WebApp.Start<PushServerStartup>("http://localhost:8080/events");
```

Here is the startup class I am using:

```cs
public class PushServerStartup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapHubs();
    }
}
```

I am running this inside a console application that does a lot of other things including routing trace writing to certain files etc. But all of a sudden (when activating the OWIN hosting) I am seeing trace messages written to the console that are normally routed somewhere else.

Obviously there are some trace listeners active in the OWIN hosting framework. How can I switch them off?

Comment: I see the same but seems to disappear when building in release so I guess the trace listener is only added in debug builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself. After studying the Katana source code it seems like you need to register your own `ITraceOutputFactory` instance to overrule the default trace listener (which is writing to the console).

Here is the new start call:

```cs
var dummyFactory = new DummyFactory();
var provider = ServicesFactory.Create(
    defaultServiceProvider => defaultServiceProvider.AddInstance<ITraceOutputFactory>(dummyFactory));

using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(provider, new StartOptions("http://localhost:8090")))
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And here is a dummy trace factory (maybe not the best solution but you can replace it with something serving your purpose a little better):

```cs
public class DummyFactory : ITraceOutputFactory
{
    public TextWriter Create(string outputFile)
    {
        return TextWriter.Null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 24):

I had the same issue, I was self hosting 4 instances in one process and for each request was getting 4 lots of messages traced to console.

I simply removed the TraceListener instance

```
Trace.Listeners.Remove("HostingTraceListener")
```

"HostingTraceListener" is defined in the owin source code so I guess could change
 - http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Hosting/Engine/HostingEngine.cs

I did this after

```
WebApp.Start(...
```

Comment: Only solution that actually worked for me. Microsoft.Owin.Hosting 2.0.2

Comment: Well done! That's the right solution to my issue!
If "HostingTraceListener" will change, you can loop insider Trace.Listeners and look for listener to remove. If you usually have only one listener (the default one) you can remove the others without knowing them. For example: ' while (Trace.Listeners.Count > 1)
                    Trace.Listeners.RemoveAt(1);'

Answer (score 12):

An alternative to the answer from meilke that works with latest Katana self-host (2.1.0):

```
StartOptions options = new StartOptions("http://localhost:8080/events");

// disable built-in owin tracing by using a null traceoutput
options.Settings.Add(
    typeof(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Tracing.ITraceOutputFactory).FullName,
    typeof(NullTraceOutputFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName);

using (WebApp.Start<PushServerStartup>(options))
```

NullTraceOutputFactory is similar to DummyFactory but using StreamWriter.Null instead of StringWriter:

```
public class NullTraceOutputFactory : ITraceOutputFactory
{
    public TextWriter Create(string outputFile)
    {
        return StreamWriter.Null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware that there's a multi threaded race condition using `StreamWriter.Null`, since it's also used by `Console.Write*` when no console is attached, e.g. from Windows Services. It's better to use `TextWriter.Synchronized(new StreamWriter(Stream.Null))` instead.