# Owin produces a lot of logging noise in the trace

Tags: c#, .net, owin, trace, serilog

I've got a small console application running TopShelf and using Serilog as the logging facility where I'd like to run OWIN inside. However as soon as I start the app builder, every log message gets duplicated via the trace listener and thus, printed out twice to the console.

```
// serilog sink configuration
new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Trace()
        ...
        .CreateLogger();

// topshelf
HostLogger.UseLogger(new SerilogLogWriterFactory.SerilogHostLoggerConfigurator());
```

I already found [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948363/tracelistener-in-owin-self-hosting) and included the following before I start the web host:

```
        webHostOptions.Settings.Add(typeof (ITraceOutputFactory).FullName,
            typeof (WebAppBuilder.NullTraceOutputFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName);
        Trace.Listeners.Remove("HostingTraceListener");
```

The funny thing is: When I first started the application after inserting those lines, it worked (e.g. double messages were gone.). However after I cleaned my `\bin` directory, they started to appear again. What do?

Please check out this highly professional drawing I just made which should further explain the issue:

[image: ...]

[*(zoom)*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P963j.png)