# Setting the verbosity level of OWIN self-hosting

Tags: c#, owin, katana

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948363/tracelistener-in-owin-self-hosting) deals with how to disable tracing for good. I would not like to disable it, but just steer its verbosity level.

Of course, by the look of the given answers for the question mention before, it seems I could setup OWIN to use a custonm `ITraceOutputFactory` and then do it there. But my hope is that there is a easy built-in way to do so.

Maybe through adjusting some config file? Or is there a programmatic way?

Answer (score 0):

One related way is:

```
    private static void SetTraceLevel(HttpConfiguration config, TraceLevel level)
    {
        SystemDiagnosticsTraceWriter traceWriter = config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        traceWriter.MinimumLevel = level;
    }
```

This sets the tracing level for the Web API if you have that hosted in the OWIN.