# How do I stop NCalc from writing to the console?

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics, ncalc

I'm using NCalc to do mathematical evaluations in a Console application. It keeps spewing tons of information to the console (Specifically when the Evaluate() function is executed). I was unable to find documentation to stop this. For example:

```
MyApp.exe Information: 0 : Expression added to cache: 18.855520754*45.5445916666667/100
MyApp.exe Information: 0 : Information: 0 : Expression retrieved from cache: 16*10
MyApp.exe Information: 0 : Expression added to cache: 18.855520754*45.5445916666667/100
MyApp.exe Information: 0 : Expression added to cache: 18.855520754*45.5445916666667/100
MyApp.exe Information: 0 : Expression added to cache: 45.5445916666667/6
MyApp.exe Information: 0 : Expression added to cache: 45.5445916666667/6
```

Where do I define the output verbosity for NCalc?
Thanks

Here is what my App.config looks like (I removed appSettings section. Also, The logging section you see here is for Quartz.NET):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <common>
    <logging>
      <!--Used by Quartz-->
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Simple.ConsoleOutLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging">
        <arg key="level" value="Warn" />
        <!--All / Debug / Info / Warn / Error / Fatal / Off-->
        <arg key="showLogName" value="true" />
        <arg key="showDataTime" value="true" />
        <arg key="dateTimeFormat" value="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:fff" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>



  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Cors" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="StackExchange.Redis.StrongName" publicKeyToken="c219ff1ca8c2ce46" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.6.0" newVersion="1.2.6.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>


<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" name="MySQL Data Provider" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.10.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data></configuration>
```

Comment: 1) What does your *logging* configuration look like? Did you try *raising* the default logging level to something above Information? 2) Which NCalc package are you using? [This one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ncalc/) is 7 years old and use's [.NET's own Tracing framework](https://github.com/sheetsync/NCalc/blob/master/Evaluant.Calculator/Expression.cs#L90) at the `Information` level

Comment: The .NET tracing framework is [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/tracing-and-instrumenting-applications). You can configure [multiple listeners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/how-to-create-and-initialize-trace-listeners) eg, console or file. You can also configure the verbosity per [source or listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/how-to-use-tracesource-and-filters-with-trace-listeners).

Comment: I'm using "ncalc by sebastienros" from NuGet. Version 1.3.8
I don't think I have any relevant config in App.config for it. So I need to add something in App.Config to make it use "default" logging level? I'm not sure how by looking at the links you added

Comment: What's weird to me is that if I do Trace.TraceInformation("some text"); in my own code, it does not show up anywhere. and this is the command being used inside ncalc (I looked at the source code just now)

Comment: and what does *your* app.config look like? `Trace.Information` won't write anything unless you tell it to. Which package did you use? What does *that* source code look like? This is a 7 year old, abandoned package that's been repackaged by a lot of people. You'll have to check the actual source code to understand what each person did with the original code

Comment: BTW you *can* modify the trace configuration at runtime. Perhaps someone did just that. I'd look for a different library though instead of trying to understand how an old library works

Comment: Okay, I added to the question my App.Config. I saw that indeed it is 7 years old but it seems to work fine and there is no replacement it seems. I think what I have is not a repackaged version (it has 178k downloads according to nuget). I'll check out modifying it at runtime. Thanks

Comment: In the end my issue was Owin.Hosting was setting the Trace. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948363/tracelistener-in-owin-self-hosting solved it. Thanks for your help Panagiotis Kanavos

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else stumbles across this. The statements are coming from the `Expression.cs` file within NCalc. It has several calls that use `Trace`:

```
Trace.TraceInformation("Expression retrieved from cache: " + expression)
...
Trace.TraceInformation("Expression added to cache: " + expression);
...
Trace.TraceInformation("Cache entry released: " + key);
```

`System.Diagnostics.Trace` is sealed and the `TraceListenerCollection` is static. I couldn't find a simple way of disabling "just" NCalc's traces. All trace listeners registered in your app in that collection will receive these messages. This includes the "Default" listener -- which is what was relaying the messages in my case.

As of right now, I've just got "Default" turned off entirely in my web.config, which suppresses the console output, and critically, ***vastly*** improves debugging performance in NCalc heavy sections:

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

The only way to remove them (assuming you want to leave TRACE enabled as you're using it elsewhere) seems to be to register a custom `TraceListener` / inherit from `DefaultTraceListener`. Then you can implement new `Write` / `WriteLine` methods which filter out NCalc's traces. Either by matching the string syntax or by inspecting the stack-trace and suppressing any traces that originated from the NCalc assembly.

The former seems clunky, and the latter excessive & wastes undo CPU cycles. So if anyone has a better approach, I'd be keen to hear it, lol.